# Solving system of equation in two variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

If $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are the real solutions of two equation $$x^3-3xy^2=2005$$ and $$y^3-3x^2y=2004$$ then find value of 
$$\frac{y_1 y_2 y_3}{2(y_1-x_1)(y_2-x_2)(y_3-x_3)}.$$

I added and subtracted the two equation to get $$(x-y)(x^2+4xy+y^2)=1$$ and $$(x+y)(x^2-4xy+y^2)=4009$$ but couldn't proceed further. Then I used vieta's formulas in second equation  to get $y_1 y_2 y_3=2004$ but couldn't resolve the denominator similarly. Now I am stuck please help me out.

Comment: can you fix your typos please?

Comment: Typos are fixed now !!!

Comment: Do $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $y_1, y_2, y_3$ have some order relationship? Because I'm not sure $(y_1-x_1)(y_2-x_2)(y_3-x_3)$ will be well defined.

Comment: The Question doesn't describe so.

Comment: @Blex : That's exactly what I thought at first, but $$ (x-y)^3 = x^3 - 3x^2 y + 3xy^2 -y^3. $$ And adding rather than subtracting also leaves sign problems.

Comment: Michael Hardy is right

Comment: @Blex : You need to be somewhat detail-oriented: If you had $x^3 + 3xy^2$ and $y^3 + 3x^2 y,$ then you'd be right.

Comment: ok, now i see my error; -/+ on wrong places

Comment: @MichaelHardy Right. What *does* hold is $\,(x-iy)^3=2005 + 2004 i\,$ but I don't see that being useful.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
2005 & = x^3 - 3xy^2 = x^3 + 3x(iy)^2 \\[10pt]
2004 & = y^3 - 3yx^2 = y^3 + 3y(ix)^2 \\[10pt]
2005 -i2004 & = (x+iy)^3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  by brute force, let $t=x/y\,$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
t^3 - 3 t = \frac{2005}{y^3} \\[5px]
-3t^2 + 1 = \frac{2004}{y^3}
\end{align}
$$

Dividing the two:

$$
\frac{t^3-3t}{-3t^2+1} = \frac{2005}{2004} \quad\iff\quad 2004 t^3 + 6015 t^2 -6012 t - 2005 = 0
$$

Now $\;\displaystyle \frac{{y_1 \cdot y_2 \cdot y_3}}{{2(y_1-x_1)(y_2-x_2)(y_3-x_3)}} = \frac{1}{2(1-t_1)(1-t_2)(1-t_3)}\,$ can be calculated using Vieta's.

Comment: Was going to post the same solution :) (+1) $(x-t_1)(x-t_2)(x-t_3)=x^3+\frac{6015}{2004}x^2-\frac{6012}{2004}x-\frac{2005}{2004}$

Comment: Neatly answered thank you so much

Comment: @RohanShinde Glad it helped. There might exist a "nicer" solution, but I don't see it offhand.